# JTextField tailoring

Tags: java, swing

I have been working with a JPanel, named infoPanel in the provided code, that I want to be able to precisely place a JTextField with a JLabel in front of it.  I have tried adding a JLabel to it and not been able to place where I want it.  I want to put it about 20 pixels lower than it is in the provided code and in front of it I want to add the JTextField.  I also would like to make the JTextField read only.

1. How can I precisely place JTextField and JLabels?
2. What is the best practice for this?

   ```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
   import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
   import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
   import java.util.*;
   import java.util.List;

   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   public class DrawPanelMain extends JPanel {

   private static final int PREF_W = 1200;
   private static final int PREF_H = 700;
   private List<Point> POINT_LIST = Arrays.asList(new Point[] {
           new Point(40, 40),
           new Point(40, 100),
           new Point(40, 160),
           new Point(40, 220),
           new Point(40, 280),
           new Point(40, 340),
           new Point(40, 400),
           new Point(40, 460),
           new Point(40, 520),
           new Point(40, 580),
           new Point(100, 100),
           new Point(100, 160),
           new Point(100, 220),
           new Point(100, 280),
           new Point(100, 340),
           new Point(100, 400),
           new Point(100, 460),
           new Point(100, 520),
           new Point(100, 580),
           new Point(160, 160),
           new Point(160, 220),
           new Point(160, 280),
           new Point(160, 340),
           new Point(160, 400),
           new Point(160, 460),
           new Point(160, 520),
           new Point(160, 580),
           new Point(220, 220),
           new Point(220, 280),
           new Point(220, 340),
           new Point(220, 400),
           new Point(220, 460),
           new Point(220, 520),
           new Point(220, 580),
           new Point(280, 280),
           new Point(280, 340),
           new Point(280, 400),
           new Point(280, 460),
           new Point(280, 520),
           new Point(280, 580),
           new Point(340, 340),
           new Point(340, 400),
           new Point(340, 460),
           new Point(340, 520),
           new Point(340, 580),
           new Point(400, 400),
           new Point(400, 460),
           new Point(400, 520),
           new Point(400, 580),
           new Point(460, 460),
           new Point(460, 520),
           new Point(460, 580),
           new Point(520, 520),
           new Point(520, 580),
           new Point(580, 580)
   });
   private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
   private int tabIndex = 0;

   public DrawPanelMain() {
       JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
       JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
       btnPanel.add(new JButton(new AddSwitchAction("Add Switch Panel")));
       btnPanel.add(new JButton(new PushConfigAction("Push Config")));
       btnPanel.add(new JButton(new ActivateAllAction("Activate All")));  //Button I want to work with
       infoPanel.add(new JTextField(20));

       setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
       add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
           return super.getPreferredSize();
       }
       return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class AddSwitchAction extends AbstractAction {
           public AddSwitchAction(String name) {
               super(name);
               int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
               putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
           }

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           tabIndex++;
           String title = "Switch " + tabIndex;
           DrawPanel2 tabComponent = new DrawPanel2(POINT_LIST);
           tabbedPane.add(title, tabComponent);
       }
   }

   private class PushConfigAction extends AbstractAction {
       public PushConfigAction(String name) {
           super(name);
           int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
           putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
       }

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           /*Add code sending the configuration to the switch panel*/
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DrawPanelMain.this, "Configuration    Pushed to Panel");
       }
   }

   private class ActivateAllAction extends AbstractAction {
       public ActivateAllAction(String name) {
           super(name);
           int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(1);
           putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
       }

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           Component comp = tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
           if (comp instanceof DrawPanel2) {
               DrawPanel2 drawPanel = (DrawPanel2) comp;
               drawPanel.activateAll();
           }
       }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
       DrawPanelMain mainPanel = new DrawPanelMain();
       final double version = 0.1;
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("RF Connection Panel " + version);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
       frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               createAndShowGui();
           }
       });
   }

   }

   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   class DrawPanel2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int OVAL_WIDTH = 40;
   private static final Color INACTIVE_COLOR = Color.RED;
   private static final Color ACTIVE_COLOR = Color.green;
   private List<Point> points;
   private List<Ellipse2D> ellipses = new ArrayList<>();
   private Map<Ellipse2D, Color> ellipseColorMap = new HashMap<>();

   public DrawPanel2(List<Point> points) {
       this.points = points;
       for (Point p : points) {
           int x = p.x - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
           int y = p.y - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
           int w = OVAL_WIDTH;
           int h = OVAL_WIDTH;
           Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
           ellipses.add(ellipse);
           ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, INACTIVE_COLOR);
        }

       MyMouseAdapter mListener = new MyMouseAdapter();
       addMouseListener(mListener);
       addMouseMotionListener(mListener);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
       g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
       for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
           g2.setColor(ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse));
           g2.fill(ellipse);
       }
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
       @Override
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
           for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
               if (ellipse.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                   Color c = ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse);
                   c = (c == INACTIVE_COLOR) ? ACTIVE_COLOR : INACTIVE_COLOR;
                   ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, c);
               }
           }
           repaint();
       }
   }

   public void activateAll() {
       for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
           ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, ACTIVE_COLOR);
       }
       repaint();
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: *"What is the best practice for this?"* Use one or more layout managers, `Insets` and `Border`s

Comment: OK I will do some research on those, thanks.

Comment: Also, there's no `JLabel` in your example code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I precisely place JTextField and JLabels?

Don't focus on this, focus on making the flow of the UI make sense and easy for the user.

> What is the best practice for this?

Use one or more appropriate layout managers, `Insets` where the layout manager supports them and/or `Border`s where they don't

For example...

[image: Label and field]

```
JPanel fields = new JPanel();
fields.add(new JLabel("Hello: "));
fields.add(new JTextField(20));
fields.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 2, 0, 2));

infoPanel.add(fields);
```

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details

Comment: This is only a very basic example, you may need to use different layout managers to achieve the final result your after ;)

Comment: year I know but you steered me in the right direction.

Comment: so I have been trying to add another text box and label under this one but it shows up to the right of it.  What do you suggest?